# Name from Objects is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, arraylist

im having a problem with a value from an object. I dont understand why is undefined??

Im getting these data from endpoint and storing in state like this:

```
const [manualdata, setManualData] = useState([]);
setManualData(response.data.basket.typedProducts);
```

This is the console log from response.data.basket.typetProducts:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "_id": "60300df677916c2f2fe033b6",
    "name": "Dardhe",
    "quantity": 2,
  },
  Object {
    "_id": "60337d3d77916c2f2fe033ba",
    "name": "Molle",
    "quantity": 14,
  },
] TYPED PRODUCTS
```

When Im console logging **manualdata.name it says undefined**, can somebody explain it to me why and how to get to name?

Comment: It is undefined cos the ```manualdata``` is an array based on your console log. Try ```manualdata[0].name```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way for single `name`

```
manualdata[0].name
```

To filter out just names, you can do is

```
const names = manualdata.map(item => item.name);
```

// output => ["name1", "name2"]

Comment: Yes but I need to find or filter the name, how to do that ??

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you want by updating the question?

Comment: ```const names = manualdata.map(item => {
        if(item.name == someName){
            console.log("Match")
        }
});```

You can also use ```manualdata.filter()```

Comment: Im adding products to endpoint, I want to check if that name does exist dont add it anymore

Comment: @ZahirMasoodi thank you it solved my problem